# Symfony 3 : Routing with subdomain don't work on prod

Tags: php, symfony, subdomain

This will make 6 hours that I am on the problem, I have a routing with host requirements, to handle subdomain. It works perfectly in dev but in staging this repeats me the same error no matter what I do:

```
No route found for "GET /login"" at /var/www/app/var/cache/prod/classes.php
```

Here is my routing :

```
app_front_office:
    resource: "@AppFrontOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    host: "%front_office_domain%"

app_back_office:
   resource: "@AppBackOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
   prefix:   /
   host: "%back_office_domain%"
```

security.yml :

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous:  true
        form_login:
            login_path: app_back_office_security_login
            check_path: app_back_office_security_login
        logout:
            path: app_back_office_security_logout
            target: app_back_office_dashboard_index
        remember_me:
            secret: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 2630000
            path: app_back_office_dashboard_index
            always_remember_me: true
            domain: '%cookie_domain%'
            user_provider: main_provider

access_control:
    - { host: '%back_office_domain%',path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { host: '%back_office_domain%',path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

parameters.yml :

```
cookie_domain: .domain.com
front_office_domain: staging.domain.com
back_office_domain: bo-staging.domain.com
```

debug:router :

```
app_front_office_homepage                     ANY        ANY staging.domain.com      /                                  
fos_js_routing_js                                ANY        ANY      ANY                     /js/routing.{_format}              
app_back_office_dashboard_index               GET        ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /                                  
app_back_office_security_login                GET|POST   ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /login                             
app_back_office_security_logout               ANY        ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /logout                            
app_back_office_subscription_plan_list_ajax   GET        ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /subscriptions/list                
app_back_office_user_index                    GET        ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /users                             
app_back_office_user_profile                  GET        ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /users/profile/{userId}            
app_back_office_user_update_field_ajax        POST       ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /users/updateField                 
app_back_office_user_delete_ajax              DELETE     ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /users/delete/{userId}             
app_back_office_user_recover_ajax             POST       ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /users/recover/{userId}            
app_back_office_user_list_ajax                GET        ANY      bo-staging.domain.com   /users/list
```

nginx conf :

```
    server {
        listen       443 default_server ssl;

        server_name staging.domain.com api-staging.domain.com dashboard-staging.domain.com bo-staging.domain.com;
        root /var/www/wapp/web;


        ssl on;
            ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/domain_com.key;
        #   ssl_session_timeout  5m;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;


        location / {
            try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
        }
        # PROD
        location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
            internal;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            return 404;
        }

        error_log /var/log/nginx/app_error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/app_access.log;
    }


    # HTTP server
    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name  staging.domain.com api-staging.domain.com dashboard-staging.domain.com bo-staging.domain.com;
        root /var/www/app/web;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help, I will go crazy if I can not fix the problem :p

Comment: Did you clear the prod cache? I assumed you have dns wildcards and Apache configuration on your hosting.

Comment: What url are you trying to access?

Comment: @MehmetSoylu Yes I have clear the cache, no wildcards there is subdomain records and a nginx server.

Comment: @JakubMatczak I've try all the url.

Comment: can you check the route debug in terminal ?

Comment: *all the url* is not an information. If you expect to get any help, try to answer questions as specific as possible. You've pasted an error related to routing and didn't say when (under what url) you're getting it. Good luck.

Comment: @MehmetSoylu Yes I had already check and see nothing explaining, I edit the question with the debug.

Comment: everything looks fine. my last advice is try same env with apache virtualhosts.  if the problem is about nginx you can see maybe.

Comment: Have you run debug:router with prod environment?

Comment: @MehmetSoylu Ok I'm gonna try, but I have the same env with nginx on local machine :/ Thank you

Comment: @E.K. Yes it's from prod env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone for your help, I found the anwser. The load balancer health checker was configured to check the "/login" path and I wasn't aware of this configuration so that explain the error.